# Does an algebraic irrational number always have all digits from the base?

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

If you take $\sqrt{2}$ in base $10$ and remove all digits $2$-$9$ you will get something like $1.1100010010101$... which i believe to be transcendental, and
it got me curious, could there be an algebraic irrational number made of just $0$'s and $1$'s? does an algebraic irrational number need to have all digits from the base?

Comment: I believe this is open. It is conjectured that every algebraic irrational is *normal*, which is even stronger than what you propose, but the normality of any particular algebraic irrational is still open.